# How do I set a separate message for warning vs alert in terraform for Datadog?

Tags: terraform, monitor, threshold, datadog

I'm setting up a monitor that looks like this:

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "queue_size_critical" {
  message = "High Priority"
  name    = "too many messages in queue"
  query   = "max(last_10m):max:aws.sqs.approximate_number_of_messages_visible{aws_account:<account>,queuename:<queuename>} > 10"
  type    = "metric alert"
  tags    = my_tags
  thresholds = {
    ok = 0
    warning = 1
    critical = 10
  }
  renotify_interval = 1440
}
```

I've also got a widget that looks like this:

```
widget {
  alert_value_definition {
    alert_id = datadog_monitor.queue_size_critical.id
    title    = datadog_monitor.queue_size_critical.name
  }
}
```

I'd like to define two different messages, one of which will be sent when the "warning" threshold is crossed, and the other which will be sent when the "critical" threshold is crossed.

How can I do this?

Is this correct?

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "queue_size_critical" {
      message = "{{#is_alert}}High Priority{{/is_alert}}
                 {{#is_warning}}Low priority{{/is_warning}}
                 This gets sent every time, in every message."
      name    = "too many messages in queue"
      query   = bla bla bla
      ...etc...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's all handled in the `message` attribute with [conditional logic variables](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/notifications/?tab=is_alert#conditional-variables).

If, for example, you define your `message` value to be this...

```
{{#is_alert}}
High Priority @pagerduty
{{/is_alert}}

{{#is_warning}}
Medium Priority @slack-mychannel
{{/is_warning}}

You should reference [this dashboard](mydashboardlink) to see how bad this is and follow [these steps](myrunbook) to resolve the situation.
```

... then ...

1. when your monitor crosses the alert threshold, it will include "High Priority" in the message and it will send a notification to your pagerduty integration,
2. when it crosses the warn threshold it will include "Medium Priority" and send a notification to your slack channel "mychannel", and
3. the "you should reference" part with interesting links would always show up.

Comment: I saw the conditional logic variables in the documentation, but my issue is that I don't know how to use them in the terraform (I could only find documentation regarding using them in the Datadog web UI). Could you possibly show an example of how you would integrate your answer here into my posted terraform code?

Comment: I edited my message to show what I think is the correct way to go about it. Can you confirm?

Comment: Great, thanks a ton! I didn't know it was as simple as just putting it all in the message string.